# AJAX cannot return Json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, jquery

I'm trying to post a piece of Json data to AJAX and get a "upvote_message" in return. However, the "upvote_message" is returned as undefined.

Code:

```
<div class="media">
<div class="media-body">
<p align="right">
<span href="javascript:;" rel="1" class="upvote">Text to be replaced</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

$('.media .media-body .upvote').click(function(){ 

var this_a = $(this);
var comment_id = $(this).closest('span').attr('rel');

$.ajax({ 
type:"POST", 
url: base_url + "/upvote",
data:{comment_id : comment_id}, 
dataType: "json",

success: function(data,status){
if(data.state == 'succ')
{
this_a.html(upvote_msg);  
}
else
{
this_a.html(upvote_msg);
}
}
});

}); 
}); 
</script>
```

PHP

```
public function upvote (){  

$comment_id = $this->input->post('comment_id');

if($comment_id==5){
echo json_encode(array('state' => 'succ','upvote_msg'=>'haha')); 
}

else{ 
echo json_encode(array('state' => 'fail','upvote_msg'=>'bam')); 
} 
exit();

}
}
```

The PHP and AJAX's write-into part works fine. Data is also registered in database.

The issue is that the 'upvote_msg' is shown as "undefined" when being returned to the Javascript.

How to fix this? Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`upvote_msg` is a property of the `data` object so it should be `data.upvote_msg`

Answer (score 1):

To get upvote_msg value you have to use

```
data.upvote_msg or data["upvote_msg"]
```